# Can I link a DVB-T2 channel frequency in a m3u list?

Tags: android, android-tv, m3u, iptv

Since I got a device which is both IPTV Player and DVB-T2 receiver, I'm guessing if I could compose an hybrid m3u list containing not only stream channels, but some DVB-T2 channels frequencies as well.

This way I would have something like this for the common stream channel:

`#EXTINF:1, tvg-id="MyStreamChannel.com" tvg-logo=img/mystreamchannel.png" tvg-name="My Stream Channel HD" group-title="Favourites",My Stream Channel HD
http://my_stream_font.com/mystreamchannel.ts`

... and something like this, for a DVB-T2 channel:

`#EXTINF:1, tvg-id="TerrestrialChannel.com" tvg-logo=img/terrestrialchannel.png" tvg-name="Terrestrial Channel HD" group-title="Favourites",Terrestrial Channel HD
1_0_1_218C_4_13E_EEEE0000_0_0_0`

Is it technically possible, maybe typing the code differently?

Answer (score 0):

To play DVB frequencies in your m3u manifest, you would need a player that supports this functionality.

I think you may find that most players do not, but VLC player does, or certainly did - there is an example manifest in this discussion: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=79472

For the player to actually be able to play both 'regular' IP streams and tune to and play the DVB frequencies requires the player typically to use multiple underlying players in the device - typically DVB content in a STB uses a different media pipeline and player than IP content.